# Receiving error: "Variable used in loop condition not modified in loop body"

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm new to coding and I've stumbled across a problem. I'm trying to write a program which takes a float from the user and multiplies it by 100. I then want to subtract 25 from this number as many times as possible (until it reaches some number < 25, at which point I want it to stop). I would like there to be a counter which increments by 1 every time 25 is subtracted, that is, I want to record the number of times 25 has been subtracted from the original number and then I want to printf the result.

Here is my attempt at coding the program:

```
int main(void)
{
    float input = get_float("%s", "Input: ");
    float w = input * 100;
    {
        for (int q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25)
        for (int c = 0; q > 24; c++)
        printf("%i", c);
    }
}
```

The error I receive is on the for `(int c = 0; q > 24; c++)` section, and the error given is `variable 'q' used in loop condition not modified in loop body`.

It seems as though my use of q in the condition for the second loop is causing the problem, but I want the second loop to run until q reaches <24 and I don't know how to do it without simply putting q > 24 as the condition.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ask yourself when will this loop for (int c = 0; q > 24; c++)  stop its iterations.

Comment: `I want the second loop to run until q reaches <24` But `q` will _never_ reach `<24` as it is not modified in your second loop.

Comment: Think about the loop `for (int c = 0; q > 24; c++)` a little bit more. Try to explain it to [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or friend or other suitable alternative).

Comment: I think I understand the criticism being made here, that the loop will run indefinitely. However, I am still unsure as to how to make the second loop stop when the first loop stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a second loop here.  What you want is to declare `c` outside of the loop, initialize it to 0, increment it inside the loop, then print it when the loop is done.

```
int c = 0;
for (int q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25) {
    c++;
}
printf("%i", c);
```

Comment: Goodness me, you guys are quick! This was what I needed, thank you kindly.